# Definition of continuity of ordinal function

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

In the book Introduction to Set Theory' by Hrbacek and Jech, chapter $6$ Ordinal Numbers, section $6$ Normal Form, I don't understand the definition of continuity of ordinal numbers.

Ordinal functions $\alpha+ \beta, \alpha \cdot \beta, \alpha^\beta$ are continuous in the second variable:

If $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal and $\beta=\sup_{\nu < \gamma} \beta_{\nu} $, then

$\alpha+\beta=\sup_{\nu < \gamma}(\alpha + \beta), \alpha \cdot \beta=\sup_{\nu < \gamma}(\alpha \cdot \beta_{\nu}), \alpha^{\beta}=\sup_{\nu < \gamma}\alpha^{\beta_\nu}$

Can anyone explain to me what is the meaning of continuity of ordinal functions?

Comment: I don't know, but my first guess is that you can equip your set with the order topology, and continuity is obtained with respect to these topologies. Would that make sense?

Answer (score 6):

Continuity just means that taking $\sup$ before or after applying the function gives the same result. This is the same with real numbers, that given a convergent sequence $x_n\to x$, then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

So when we say that ordinal addition is continuous we say that $$\sup\{\beta+\gamma\mid\gamma<\delta\}=\beta+\sup\{\gamma\mid\gamma<\delta\}=\beta+\delta.$$

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I should say $\lim_{\beta \rightarrow \alpha} f(\beta) = f(\lim_{\beta \rightarrow \alpha} \beta)$, since $f$ [might not be monotonic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156458/whats-the-definition-of-limit-of-setsesp-ordinals-in-set-theory).

Comment: Well, yes. The question was talking about monotonic functions, though. :-)