# Proving $\alpha+\beta=\sup\{\alpha+\beta_{\delta}:\delta<\gamma\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

For ordinals $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, if $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal and $\beta = \sup\{\beta_{\delta}:\delta<\gamma\}$, why does below expression hold, 
$$\alpha+\beta=\alpha + \sup\{\beta_{\delta}:\delta<\gamma\}=\sup\{\alpha+\beta_{\delta}:\delta<\gamma\}$$
Simply what I am asking is why,
$$\alpha+\beta=\sup\{\alpha+\beta_{\delta}:\delta<\gamma\}$$
holds? I tried to prove it by considering another $\sup$ like $z$ then trying to prove that the $\sup$ we've found is less that $z$. I don't know why and where in proof **$\gamma$ is limit ordinal** is required?!

**Edit** I simply want to prove continuity property of ordinal addition. There was a question asked about what continuity of ordinals is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946657/definition-of-continuity-of-ordinal-function).

Comment: What is $\beta_\delta$?

Comment: What does hold for $\gamma$ a limit, is $\alpha + \gamma = \sup \{\alpha + \beta: \beta < \gamma\}$. Maybe that's what you mean? For some this is (part of) the *definition* of addition.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, both say the same thing.

Comment: No they don’t say the same thing. But what’s your definition of addition?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma My reference is Jech book