# Continuity of cardinal power function

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

So, given an infinite cardinal $\kappa$, what can we say about the continuity of the function $$\begin{align}f : \text{Card} &\longrightarrow \text{Card} \\ \lambda &\longmapsto \lambda^\kappa \end{align}$$ 
? Can we characterize the class of limit cardinals which are discontinuity points? If it is a trivial matter, could you give me nonetheless a hint? Can we at least characterize a class of infinite cardinals that are continuity points?

Thanks

Comment: What is the topology on Card?

Comment: @DonAntonio The order topology, with some caveats, seeing as how Card is a proper class. In set theory it's better to say $f$ is continuous if $\sup_{\xi<\gamma} f(\alpha_\xi)=f(\alpha)$ whenver $\langle \alpha_\xi:\xi<\gamma\rangle$ is an increasing sequence with $\sup_{\xi<\gamma}\alpha_\xi=\alpha$.

Comment: This is far from trivial. An easy example is any limit cardinal $\lambda$ of cofinality $\kappa$ such that $\rho^\kappa\le\lambda$ for all $\rho<\lambda$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo . Verily. If $\lambda$ is a strong limit cardinal then $\lambda^{cf(\lambda)}=2^{\lambda}>\lambda.$ In the case $\kappa=\omega$: (i). If GCH then $\sup_{(x<\omega_{\omega})}f(x)=\omega_{\omega} < f(\omega_{\omega})$. (ii).But MA (Martin's Axiom) plus $2^{\omega}>\omega_{\omega}$ implies that $f(x)=f(\omega)= 2^{\omega}$ whenever $\omega\le x<2^{\omega}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet there seems to be some formatting problem in the comment

Comment: @Daniel: I fixed your comment (the subscript of the $\sup$ was missing a `}`...

Comment: @Reveillark More concisely, $f$ is continuous [iff](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946657/definition-of-continuity-of-ordinal-function/946896#comment7433082_946896) $f(\lim_{\beta \rightarrow \alpha} \beta) = \lim_{\beta \rightarrow \alpha} f(\beta)$.

Comment: @user76284 so concise it's tautological