# Proof that addition of an ordinal with a non-zero limit ordinal is always a limit ordinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I wanna show that $\alpha + \beta$ is a limit ordinal where $\alpha$ is an ordinal  and $\beta$ is a non-zero limit ordinal.

The less-smart way is to say that it is clearly non-zero since $\beta$ is non-zero and then show that $\alpha + \beta$ is not a successor ordinal, therefore has to be limit ordinal. How can this be proven? Can somebody prove this or perhaps directly prove that it is a limit ordinal?

Secondly, is it true that $\alpha . \beta $ and $\beta . \alpha$ are also limit ordinals? My argument is that using another ordinal $\gamma$, where $\alpha = \gamma + 1$, we can write the multiplications as $\alpha. (\gamma + 1 ) = \alpha . \gamma + \alpha$ and $ (\gamma + 1 ) . \alpha = \gamma . \alpha + \alpha$ respectively. Using the previous part, the results are also limit ordinals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to follow directly from the definitions, at least as given on Wikipedia in [Ordinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic) and [Limit ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_ordinal):

> ...if β is a limit ordinal then α + β is the limit of α + δ for all δ < β.

> Addition is strictly increasing and continuous in the right argument:
>
> $$ \delta<\gamma\Rightarrow \alpha+\delta <\alpha+\gamma$$

Hence the set $\{\alpha + \delta \mid \delta < \beta\}$ has no greatest element.

> The union of a nonempty set of ordinals that has no greatest element is then always a limit ordinal.

I think for multiplication you meant to write $\beta (\gamma + 1) = \beta \gamma + \beta$. This works if $\alpha$ is a nonzero successor ordinal, but there was no such restriction mentioned (it could be a limit ordinal itself). Also, distribution from the right doesn't work in general, so $(\gamma + 1) \beta$ can't be expanded. However, both these problems can be overcome by essentially the same argument: if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, then $\alpha \beta$ is defined to be the limit of $\{ \alpha \delta \mid \delta < \beta\}$, and ordinal multiplication is strictly increasing in the right argument.

Comment: You quoted that 'addition is strictly increasing and continuous in the right argument'. What does it mean by 'addition is continuous in the right argument'? What's the definition of the continuity here?

Comment: I guess it means that the limit of x + (elements of a convergent sequence) = x + (limit of the sequence). Same thing was asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946657/definition-of-continuity-of-ordinal-function