# Continuity of ordinal operations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

As it is stated in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946657/definition-of-continuity-of-ordinal-function) question, in the book *Introduction to set theory* by Hrbacek and Jech it is stated that ordinal arithmetic functions are continuous in the second variable, that meaning that if $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal and $\beta = \sup_{\nu<\gamma} \{\beta_\nu\}$, then

$$\alpha+\beta=\sup_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha+\beta_\nu)\\\alpha \cdot\beta=\sup_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha \cdot\beta_\nu) \\ \alpha^\beta=\sup_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha^{\beta_\nu})$$

I've proven it in the following way.

First, if the set $\{\beta_\nu| \nu < \gamma\}$ has a maximum, say $\beta_{\nu_0}$, then $\beta=\beta_{\nu_0}$ and then for any $\nu < \gamma$ and using inequality properties for the ordinal operations
$$\alpha+\beta_{\nu} \leq \alpha + \beta_{\nu_0}\\ \alpha \cdot\beta_{\nu} \leq \alpha \cdot \beta_{\nu_0} \\ \alpha^{\beta_{\nu}} \leq \alpha^{\beta_{\nu_0}}$$
So, the equalities are clear in this case.

On the other hand, if the set $\{\beta_\nu| \nu < \gamma\}$ doesn't have a maximum, then $\beta$ is a limit ordinal. If not $\beta=\delta+1$ for some ordinal $\delta < \beta$, so there exists some $\beta_\nu$ such that $\delta < \beta_\nu$ and then $\beta=\delta+1 \leq \beta_\nu \leq \beta$ obtaining that $\beta=\beta_\nu$ and contradicting the non existence of maximum.

Then, we have by definition that
$$\alpha+\beta=\sup_{\delta<\beta}(\alpha+\delta)\\\alpha \cdot\beta=\sup_{\delta<\beta}(\alpha \cdot\delta) \\ \alpha^\beta=\sup_{\delta<\beta}(\alpha^{\delta})$$

Now, again using inequality properties for the ordinal operations is clear that $$\sup_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha+\beta_\nu) \leq \alpha+\beta\\ \sup_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha \cdot\beta_\nu) \leq \alpha \cdot\beta \\ \sup_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha^{\beta_\nu}) \leq \alpha^{\beta}$$

For the other inequality, given any $\delta < \beta$ we have that there exists some $\nu_{\delta} < \gamma$ such that $\delta < \beta_{\nu_\delta}$, so again we have that
$$\alpha+\delta \leq \alpha + \beta_{\nu_\delta} \leq \sup_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha+\beta_\nu)\\ \alpha \cdot\delta \leq \alpha \cdot \beta_{\nu_\delta} \leq \sup_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha \cdot\beta_\nu)\\ \alpha^{\delta} \leq \alpha^{\beta_{\nu_\delta}} \leq \sup_{\nu<\gamma}(\alpha^{\beta_\nu})$$

And taking supremum over $\delta < \beta$ we get the other inequality.

Now, I have three questions:

1. Is my proof correct?
2. Why in the book it states that $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal? I think I haven't used it anywhere.
3. Is there an easy way to do it? Because, in the book is stated that follows directly from the definitions, but using order properties that are propositions and exercises in the previous section doesn't seem to be "directly" for me.

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looks good to me.
2. You don't need it. In fact if $\alpha$ is an ordinal and $X$ is a nonempty set of ordinals then you have

$$\alpha+\sup X=\sup\{\alpha+\beta:\beta\in X\}$$
$$\alpha\cdot\sup X=\sup\{\alpha\cdot\beta:\beta\in X\}$$
$$\alpha^{\sup X}=\sup\{\alpha^\beta:\beta\in X\} \quad \alpha>0$$
The proof is exactly like you did. In particular you need to use the order properties of ordinal addition, multiplication and exponentiation.

3. I don't see an easier way. Note however that the case $\gamma:=\beta$ and $\beta_v:=v$ does indeed follow from the definitions in the book when $\beta$ is a nonzero limit ordinal. Perhaps this is what the authors had in mind when they wrote "directly".